# weblogic can't handle any request

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, weblogic

Recently our weblogic hangs frequently after it was started for some hours,when it hangs,it can't process any request。
We saw the thread dump,most of the threads were doing this:

```
 "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '195' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" - Thread t@5932
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.util.Hashtable.get(Hashtable.java:335)
        at java.util.Properties.getProperty(Properties.java:774)
        at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:630)
        at oracle.net.nl.NVPair.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nl.NVFactory._readNVPair(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nl.NVFactory._readNVList(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nl.NVFactory._readNVList(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nl.NVFactory._readNVList(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nl.NVFactory._readNVPair(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nl.NVFactory.createNVPair(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.getNT(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.connect(TTC7Protocol.java:1774)
        at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:215)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:362)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:536)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:328)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.makeConnection(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:300)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionEnvFactory.createResource(ConnectionEnvFactory.java:204)
        at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.makeResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:1057)
        at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.makeResources(ResourcePoolImpl.java:982)
        at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResourceInternal(ResourcePoolImpl.java:371)
        at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:294)
        at weblogic.common.resourcepool.ResourcePoolImpl.reserveResource(ResourcePoolImpl.java:284)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.reserve(ConnectionPool.java:466)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPool.reserve(ConnectionPool.java:357)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPoolManager.reserve(ConnectionPoolManager.java:83)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.ConnectionPoolManager.reserve(ConnectionPoolManager.java:96)
        at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.connect(Driver.java:150)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.getNonTxConnection(Driver.java:647)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.connect(Driver.java:137)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:359)
        at com.xx.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:187)
        at com.xx.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:148)
        at com.xx.core.database.Database.newInstance(Database.java:816)
        at com.xx.DatabaseProvider.getDatabase(DatabaseProvider.java:10)
        at com.xx.Tools.getDatabase(Tools.java:91)
        at com.xx.PopInfo.doGet(PopInfo.java:179)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:225)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:127)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
        at com.anychart.servlet.ResourceFilter.doFilter(ResourceFilter.java:53)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:42)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3212)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:1983)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:1890)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1344)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:181)
```

Through this stacktrace,it seems all these threads was waiting for getting database connection , but when we saw the oracle,we saw a lot of inactive jdbc connection。
Why so many threads are waiting for connection but at the same time  database has so many inactie jdbc connection, how can we solve this problem, please help us ,thanks.

Comment: Just a guess of course (there is basically no information available to investigate): you are not closing your connections properly, something (probably the DB) limits the number of open connections. After you fill this pool with let's say a 1000 open connections after a few hours, the next db connection opening will hang. So your threads will hang. Investigate the DB connections.

Comment: What version of Weblogic are you using? Does these threads stay the same (i.e stuck on the same line and with the same thread ID) if you take another thread dump

Comment: @Disco3 Thanks for your reply. We are using weblogic 9.2.Used weblogic connection pool. We investigated the threads and code,mst of the  threads stay at the same place: they stopped at getting the DB connection.    Database got so many  inactive connection ,why our web app can't use them?

Comment: @GergelyBacso Thanks. I opened weblogic connection leak profile function, and didn't see any connection leak.

Comment: I am not sure how much you want to trust that tool, but ok. In your place I would rather go for something much more direct. Like geting a DBA to monitor the number of live DB connections from your server.

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace it looks they arestuck due to deadlock while accessing system property. Can you please change the jdbc driver and try. I'm not sure from which  jar file the class oracle.net.nl.NVPair is used. When I checked source code of oracle.net.nl.NVPair from couple of jars the only reference to system property I see is  `private String _linesep = System.getProperty("line.separator");` . This is  matching with your stack trace `at oracle.net.nl.NVPair.(Unknown Source)`